# Installing Jenkins on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, jenkins

I have done some googling and I cannot figure out how to install Jenkins on Arch Linux. Can anyone give me some step by step instructions?

I have a webserver running already using Nginx, With php-fpm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins is a java app.

On Ubuntu, the dependencies are:

```
$ apt-cache depends jenkins
jenkins
  Depends: daemon
  Depends: adduser
  Depends: psmisc
  Depends: <java2-runtime>
    default-jre
    gcj-4.4-jre
    gcj-jre
    openjdk-6-jre
  Conflicts: <hudson>
  Replaces: <hudson>
```

So, minimally, you'll need to get a Java 2 JRE on your Arch installation, and then proceed to manually configure Jenkins if there's no available package.

The nginx/PHP-FPM doesn't matter.  You can use nginx to proxy the Jenkins server web GUI, but the PHP side of things certainly doesn't matter for basic Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
cower -d jenkins
cd jenkins
makepkg -si
```